# Different results fetching from DB in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Am getting Different results fetching with query SQL vs hql.
Am using Spring repo and hibernate like below. But if i run the same SQL generated by hibernate the am getting for ex 5 records but my list customActivationPlans1 contains 4 records.
Why there is a difference in same SQL generated by hibernate and HQL.

Also i notice this happens when my left join is null.
join fetch c.latestRun r left join fetch r.runStatuses s has not records in DB.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private PlanRun latestRun;
```

List customActivationPlans1 = customPlanRepository.findAllDataSetSelnsAndStatusByTenantId(RequestUtil.getSessionTenant(), dataSourceType);

```
@Query("select DISTINCT c from CustomActivationPlan c join fetch c.dataSetSelections s left join fetch c.latestRun r left join fetch r.runStatuses s "
        + "where c.tenantId =:tenantId and s.tenantId =:tenantId and c.dataSourceType = :dataSourceType")
public List<CustomActivationPlan> findAllDataSetSelnsAndStatusByTenantId(@Param("tenantId") String tenantId, DataSourceType dataSourceType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest enabling hibernate SQL output in your logging config:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

This way, you can compare the generated SQL and see if there is any logic difference.

If there is no logic discrepancy, the most likely explanation is that hibernate is caching the results. This can happen either at the session level, or in the second-level cache:
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/hibernate-cache-levels-tutorial.html

It's also possible that transaction isolation is a factor. Transaction isolation controls how the database shows SQL results based on changes made in other transactions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/transaction-isolation-levels?view=sql-server-ver15

If you are querying for data immediately after persisting it, you might also need to force hibernate to flush the session:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing

Comment: Thank for your response.No difference in SQL as hibernate generated SQL only am running in MySQL console and am not using any cache in my application and it is only skipping those records where my left join condition null.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as you and where Hibernate was building the correct query, but there were some results missing compared with the SQL results.
In my case the problem was that the missing entries had the same id instead of having unique ids. The table didn`t have any constraint on, but the entity did had the [@Id](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Id.html)  witch requires that that the field to be unique.

Fixing the id solved the problem.

Try to check the missing entries maybe you have a similar problem.